# How to use pry to access a Rack middleware instance?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, pry

I'm new to using [Pry](https://rubygems.org/gems/pry), and try as I might, I can't find the right commands to access a rack middleware instance that's being run with a Sinatra app. I've set `binding.pry` in the part of the app where I have an error, but the problem is with a helper that's returning no results, and it gets the results from info put in the env by the middleware. I tried `cd`ing into `Rack::GeoIPCity`, but it didn't give me access to any instance info.

So, I can check the locals, the helper, and the env - **how do I get to the middleware** ***from the Sinatra app's code***?

e.g.

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  # inside the Sinatra app
  use Rack::GeoIPCity, :db => File.expand_path( File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "assets/GeoLiteCity.dat"))

  def geo_city_info
    h = {}
    env.select{|x| x =~ /^GEOIP/ }.each {|k,v|
      h[k.split("GEOIP_").last.downcase] = v
    }
    OpenStruct.new( h )
  end

  get "/home" do
    geo = geo_city_info
    binding.pry
  end

end
```

so at the point where `binding.pry` is called I can easily access `geo`, `env` (which is a helper provided by Sinatra to Rack's env), and I could easily add a binding inside the `geo_city_info` if I wanted. But, I can't access the `Rack::GeoIPCity` from those bindings. I'm hoping there's a command that could help me navigate to that, because it must be part of the loaded application code.

Of course, I can open up the code files for the middleware and put in the pry binding (as I install all dependent libs into /vendor using Bundler), but it'd be much better if I knew how to do this without resorting to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but you can

- Monkey patch the middleware class to use pry inside
- connect directly from the source code (what I understood you dont want)
- play around with the "use" method from Sinatra to access the middleware you want from the middleware stack

That are my ideas, hope it helps

AFTER YOUR EDITED:

Check out [this](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1389-1393), you can access the @middleware instance variable to get the used middlewares

Comment: I'd like to be able to access the instance that's been used (via `use`) from within the Sinatra app's code. I don't want to monkey patch the middleware (though that's what I'll do for now). I'll try and clean up my question to make it clearer.